# How to setup windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds programmatically?

Tags: android, user-interface, view, attributes, android-custom-view

I want to add the attribute `windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` programmatically, or in code, instead of the values-v21, because I only need it in 1 activity, and I'm using a theme selector in my app, so I can't have multiple themes.

Is possible to enable this attribute in the code? If so, then how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        }
```

Comment: my toolbar hided after using ur code